# Connection and Query with Flutter + Dart App and Postgres Database

Tags: postgresql, dart, flutter

I have to create a project for the university consisting of a website where you can simulate the purchase of tickets for events and for each ticket purchased is generated a qr code that will be saved in a database (postgres). Then with a mobile application I have to scan those qr codes and make it appear on screen if the ticket is valid or not. A colleague of mine is taking care of the web part while I'm developing the mobile application with flutter and dart code.

**My questions are:**

How do I make sure that when my application scans a qr code it connects to the database (postgres) look for the ticket code and verify its validity?

How do I create the connection and query to the database? which plugin should I use?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Good thing, there is an existing plugin for connecting to and querying PostgreSQL databases. Check out the latest [postgres](https://pub.dev/packages/postgres) plugin.

Basically what you need here is how to do CRUD with [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/protocol-overview.html). There is an existing 2 part series tutorial that is a good reference for the operations such as:

> - GET — Get a list of resources or single resource
> - POST — Create new resource
> - PUT — Update existing resource
> - DELETE — Delete a resource

See the following tutorials:

1. [Flutter: How to do CRUD with PostgreSQL? Part 1](https://medium.com/codechai/flutter-how-to-do-crud-with-postgresql-part-1-57d8d3652a31)
2. [Flutter: How to do CRUD with PostgreSQL? Part 2](https://medium.com/codechai/flutter-how-to-do-crud-with-postgresql-part-2-669894208304)